# How to monitor a child process state in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, process, posix

I have a control service that its functionality is to manage another process in the system. I have to run this process, re-run it if it's unexpectedly closed, and close it manually upon user request.

Can you please advise me how to do that in Linux? should I save the child process PID and check its state periodically? can I register to some system events that will notify me if the application running state has been changed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the control service the parent of the "other process"?

Comment: Isn't that what systemd attempts to do?

Answer (score 1):

> should I save the child process PID and check its state periodically?

No, if the child exits, the parent will receive signal `SIGCHLD`, so you can install signal handler to react on this event.

See [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) for how to install a signal handler, see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for general information about signal.